# Change delimited by comma procedure to fill combobox with range from Excel Sheet

Tags: vb.net

[image]The procedure below worked fine for me for a while. However, now the data has changed somewhat. The data is names and they are formatted as Last Name, First Name. Unfortunately, my procedure below was formatted to delimit by comma so what is doing is Last name  First Name. I do not want to do that, I would like to keep it as original.  How can I change the procedure below to do just that?

```
    Dim xlRng As Excel.Range
    Dim strRngArr As String
    Dim strChkRange As String

    Try

        xlWB = CType(Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook, Excel.Workbook)
        xlWS = DirectCast(xlWB.Sheets("allPositionsAnnualized"), Excel.Worksheet)
        xlRng = DirectCast(xlWS.Range("B6", xlWS.Range("B6").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown)), Excel.Range)
        strRngArr = String.Empty
        strChkRange = CStr(xlWS.Range("B6").Value)

        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strChkRange)) Then

            cmbSelectPosition.Enabled = False

        Else


            'Build a string array delimited by commas
            For i As Integer = 1 To xlRng.Rows.Count
                Dim xlRngCell As Excel.Range = DirectCast(xlRng.Rows(i), Excel.Range)
                strRngArr &= DirectCast(xlRngCell.Value.ToString, String) & ","

            Next

            strRngArr = strRngArr.Remove(strRngArr.Length - 1, 1)
            cmbSelectPosition.Items.AddRange(strRngArr.Split(","c))
            xlRng = Nothing
            xlWS = Nothing

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox("There no positions available to select", CType(vbOKOnly, MsgBoxStyle), "Empty Selection")

    End Try
```

I tried changing the two lines to:

```
strRngArr &= DirectCast(xlRngCell.Value.ToString, String)
```

and

```
cmbSelectPosition.Items.Add(strRngArr.ToString)
```

Which should have worked, but instead I only got the first item of my array and it was formatted as Last Name, First NameLastName.

Comment: I am happy to see that you followed my advice and moved to a "more proper" .NET version. Just a quick note: you are using lots of DirectCasts (I am under the impression that you converted this code from C#... there are plently of sample codes for this on VB.NET) which are not required; just use them when the code "complains" (something happening rarely in VB.NET). Regarding your specific problem, I am not sure if I have understood exactly what you want (out of space)

Comment: Please, tell the exact inputs and the exact outputs you are expecting, via example would be marvellous. For example: "list of names in column X and list of family names in column Y; I want to include them into the combobox in this way". An example (the more descriptive, the better) is the best way to help others to understand what you want exactly without analysing your code in detail and even despite of not having the required inputs (like in this case).

Comment: @varocarbas In column B of excel the names are displayed as Smith, John so Last Name, First Name. It is imperative that my combobox displays the items in the range in the same fashion ie: Smith, John. Right now, my code uses a delimiter (,) to display the Smith on one line and John on the line below. I need to have both displayed as one line. Hope this helps

Comment: Basically I have the srtRngArr.Split which is splitting the last name from the first name. I do not want to split it, I want to keep in the same line

Comment: Essentially, the comma was how the parameter separator. once my loop found the comma, anything after the comma goes onto the next line. So you see my issue, since my data is Last Name, First Name, once the loop sees the "," after last name it thinks it reached the end of the line and sends the first name to next line. I need them both on one line. I just do not know how to tell my loop where the next line should be if I cannot use "," as a delimiter.

Comment: I included a sample screenshot of how it looks on my spreadsheet and how it should also look on my combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, I understand that what you want is to replace the loop and the line where the `Combobox` is being populated with this:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To xlRng.Rows.Count
    cmbSelectPosition.Items.Add(DirectCast(xlRng.Rows(i), Excel.Range).Value)
Next
```

Comment: @JoseM. no problem. If you want to save time, you should try to make your questions clearer: including an example or a picture with the results transmits the ideas much better than long explanations and you would get help quicker with less effort. I wrote a comment on these lines in one of your other questions.